# Cloning TFS repository using git-tfs

Tags: git, tfs, git-tfs

I'm trying to clone a GIT repository in TFS using git-tfs using TFS 2013

```
git tfs clone http://servername:8080/tfs/DCM "$/Python"
```

Gives me:

```
error: the path $/Python you want to clone doesn't exist!
```

"DCM" is the name of the collection and "Python" is the name of the project:

[image]

I try to list the branches:

```
git tfs list-remote-branches http://servername:8080/tfs/DCM
```

which yields:

```
No TFS branches were found!
```

My instinct is that this is a syntax error, but not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Team Foundation Server (TFS) is a platform that includes code hosting (both TFVC and Git).  It's the on-premises version of VSTS.  TFVC is Team Foundation Version Control, the centralized version control system that is available in TFS and TFVC.  Despite the name, git-tfs is not necessary for git repositories hosted in TFS.  It is only necessary for TFVC repositories.  You just need to use git.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As the main developer of "git-tfs", I'm very pleased you absolutely want to use it! But there is no need of it here ;-)

The repository you want to clone is already a git repository (see the small red git icon like the one in the [git website](https://git-scm.com/)).

git-tfs is a bridge tool to be able to import a TFVC history in a local git repository.

So, you just need to do a pure git clone, that should be something like :

```
 git clone http://servername:8080/tfs/DCM/Python.git
```

The URL is provided by the web portal, at the exact page you are, in the upper right corner. You should have a 'clone' button...

Comment: Yes, if one logs into the TFS web interface and navigates to the repo it will show a "clone" button. Clicking it shows a window where you can select protocol and it will tell you the correct url