# How to clone azure deveOps project using command line?

Tags: git, azure, visual-studio, devops

I want to clone project on tfs server and use it using git command,
I am unable to find url for cloning, anyone please help.

Comment: My project is on Azure DevOps and clone button is not present there

Comment: It's also possible your TFS project is configured with TFVC instead of git, in which case there is no clone url and you'll need to use tools 3rd party tools like `gif-tfs` to clone.

Comment: [Cloning TFS repository using git-tfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48196850/cloning-tfs-repository-using-git-tfs)